# Регистр первого символа каждого слова, которое состоит из трех и более символов, должен быть интвертирован. Как сделать чтоб работало и с кириллицей?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Слово следует рассматривать как последовательность, содержащую только буквы (все остальные символы не являются частью слово). 
Например: 
Вход:

```
----------
When I was younger 
----------
I never needed 
----------
Прощай, со всех вокзалов поезда 
----------
уходят в Дальние Края
----------
```

Выход:

```
when I Was Younger
----------
I Never Needed
----------
прощай, со Всех Вокзалов Поезда
----------
Уходят в дальние края
----------
```

Код:

```
public static String toUp(String input) {
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return input;
    } else {
        for (String word : input.split(" ")) {
            if (word.length() >= 3) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0))) {
                    word = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
                } else if (Character.isLowerCase(word.charAt(0))) {
                    word = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
                }
                resultBuilder.append(word).append(" ");
            } else {
                resultBuilder.append(word).append(" ");
            }
        }
        return resultBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вы подаете входной текст этой функции? Точно ли есть пробел между словами `Needed` и `прощай`? Мне кажется, что в вашем случае между ними находится только символ переноса строки, в таком случае слово `прощай` не будет рассмотрено как отдельное слово, будет вот такое слово: `Needed\nпрощай`

Comment: Просто через файл. В самом файле любой текст который должен быть преобразован как по заданию выше.
Я думал данный код можно подправить, чтоб работало и с кириллицей...

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать

```
String s = "When I was younger\nI never needed\nПрощай, со всех вокзалов поезда\nуходят в Дальние Края";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:(\\p{Lu})|\\p{Ll})(?=\\p{L}{2})");
// Если граница слова – пробельный символ, используйте
// Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)(?:(\\p{Lu})|\\p{Ll})(?=\\p{L}{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println( m.replaceAll(r -> 
    r.group(1) == null ? r.group().toUpperCase() : r.group().toLowerCase()) 
);
```

См. [пример работы кода онлайн](https://ideone.com/QGzoW8)

Регулярное выражение находит

- `\b` - границу слова (`(?<!\S)` находит либо начало строки, либо позицию в строке, сразу перед которой есть пробельный символ)
- `(?:(\\p{Lu})|\\p{Ll})` - прописную (захватывая в подмаску №1) или строчную букву,
- `(?=\\p{L}{2})` - за которой следуют любые две буквы.

Если найдена прописная буква, она заменяется строчной и наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Оно уже работает с кириллицей. Добавьте в разделении на слова символ переноса строки: `for (String word : input.split("[ \n]"))`. Проблема в том, что введеный из файла текст содержит между словами не только пробелы, но еще и перенос строки. Например, `needed\nПрощай`, не будет разделен на слова, потому что между `needed` и `Прощай` нет пробела, поэтому у некоторых слов из текста не будет изменен регистр первой буквы.