# Регулярные выражения(Regex)

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите решить задачу с регулярными выражениями, уж очень тяжко мне они даются.

**Задание:**

> Задание должно быть решено с помощью регулярных выражений без
>   использования контейнерных классов.
>
> Вход: текст (может состоять из латиницы и кириллицы). Выход: исходный
>   текст, но регистр первого символа каждого слова, которое состоит из
>   трех и более символов, должен быть интвертирован.
>
> Словом считать последовательность содержащую только буквы (все
>   остальные символы в состав слова не входят). Создать статический метод
>   convert, который преобразовывает вход в выход.

Заглушка метода

```
public static String convert(String input) {
...
}
```

Пример Input data

```
When I was younger
I never needed
```

Пример Output

```
when I Was Younger
I Never Needed
```

Comment: А тег [tag:java-ee] какое отношение имеет к вопросу?

Comment: Уже было похожее, посмотрите вот здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1029878/236375

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регистр первого символа каждого слова, которое состоит из трех и более символов, должен быть интвертирован. Как сделать чтоб работало и с кириллицей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029818/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%81%d

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029818/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2/1029878#1029878 @nikialeksey прав, только у него ссылка битая в комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convert("When I was younger I never needed"));
}

public static String convert(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\W&&[\\d]]?[\\w&&[\\D]]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group().length() >= 3) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(sb.charAt(m.start()))) {
                sb.setCharAt(m.start(), Character.toLowerCase(sb.charAt(m.start())));
            } else {
                sb.setCharAt(m.start(), Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(m.start())));
            }

        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Если вставить цифры, или другие символы внутрь слов (например строка: `When I wa%s you35nger I ne$ver nee-ded`), то они также считаются разделителями слов и программа справляется с этим. В итоге получается строка: `when I wa%s You35Nger I ne$Ver Nee-Ded`

Comment: Мда... с кириллицей мой код не пашет(( Извиняюсь!